# How can i do a big data modelling after using elasticsearch and logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a database .sql of 3G size on tweets about the company or I work, the informations of these Tweets are categorized on tables such as age, localization, contacts, number of followers... etc, I want to migrate this database to elasticsearch I thought well to the logstash solution by a file configuration, but I want to do a big data modelling before this step so how can I model this data knowing that it has been crawler since 2015 until 2019, is this that I can create an index for each year?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste the logstash setting you have tried so far

Comment: i didn't do any logstash setting i'm thinking about modelling data before using logstash